# Django management command to delete old objects

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to schedule a delete method so cron can execute it, but I'm coming up with `CommandError: error job not completed` I stuffed up some where just don't know where :(

```
from datetime import datetime

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError

from jobs.models import Job

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Deletes the old jobs past 30days'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):

        try:
            jobs = Job.objects.filter(has_paid=True)

            for job in jobs:
                today = datetime.today()
                pub_date = job.date_published.date()

                diff = today - pub_date

                if diff.days >= 30:
                    job.delete()
        except:
            # error message
            raise CommandError('error job not completed')

        # success message
        self.stdout.write('Successfully removed all old jobs')
```

Comment: Well, if you didn't intentionally hide the errors Django is throwing, perhaps you could tell.

Comment: I think it could be substracting regular date from datetime and timezone aware date from django. Or pub_date is null. But as Daniel said, let exception be thrown so we see what is happening. ( just write "raise" after except).

Comment: What @DanielRoseman means, is that your bare `except` catches all exceptions/errors and therefore hides what's really going on. One possibility from looking at your code would be that `date_published` is either  nullable or a `DateTimeField` which could lead to an `AttributeError` or a `TypeError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A faster (only a single db query) and less error-prone way to do this would be:

```
from django.utils import timezone

past = timezone.datetime.today() - timezone.timedelta(days=30)
Job.objects.filter(has_paid=True, date_published__lte=past).delete()
```

Still, you should not use a general `except` to handle all exceptions. This is almost [never a good idea](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/doanddont.html#except), and it makes debugging that much harder.

Comment: I got error `RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Job.date_published received a naive datetime (2016-10-21 01:31:06.516105) while time zone support is active. RuntimeWarning)`

Comment: You should use the `timezone.timedelta` and `timezone.datetime.today` from `django.utils`. Django's timezone module provides the classes/functions form python's `datetime`, but timezone aware (not naive).

Comment: Thanks this works better and the best answer! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this to figure out what went wrong:

```
from datetime import datetime

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError

from jobs.models import Job

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Deletes the old jobs past 30days'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):

        jobs = Job.objects.filter(has_paid=True)

        for job in jobs:
                today = datetime.today().date()
                pub_date = job.date_published.date()

                diff = today - pub_date

                if diff.days >= 30:
                    job.delete()

        # success message
        self.stdout.write('Successfully removed all old jobs')
```